# JS bookmarklet that will reload page every 60 seconds until x is true

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to write a bookmarklet that will reload a page (Amazon delivery slots) every minute, and quit if certain conditions are met.

But how do I get the loop to continue after the reload? After the first reload, the loop is terminated.

Comment: Without seeing the code, I'd say that certain conditions are met, and looping is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript execution does not persist across pageloads. If you run a bookmarklet, and then the page gets replaced, you will have a new page, without any of your custom Javascript running. A bookmarklet's execution cannot continue after the page has been reloaded.

I see 2 main options here:

- Instead of replacing the page completely, just *fetch* the URL again via Javascript. Take the text response and parse it into a document with `DOMParser`, then examine the document for the element/conditions you want. (Won't work if the site's built-in Javascript is required to run for you to do your checks.)
- Use a userscript instead of a bookmarket. Userscripts can execute automatically on pageload. Before reloading, set a persistent variable, such as a flag in `sessionStorage`. After reloading, at the beginning of the userscript, retrieve and check the flag - if it exists, then you're "in the loop", and you can perform the required checks and reload again after 60 seconds, if needed. Once the condition is met, clear the `sessionStorage` item so that it doesn't try to continue next time you happen to load the page. Only caveat is that you'd have to have a way to initialize the userscript - perhaps have it create a button on the page to start the loop.

The second method is what I'd choose. Userscripts are also a lot more maintainable than bookmarklets IMO.

(To write userscripts, install a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/), press the "Create a new script" option on the page you want the script to run on, then type in the code you want to run on every pageload)

Comment: I would like to publish this for 'easy use' by others who are trying to order from Amazon Fresh/Whole Foods. So userscripts is too much to require. And I'm 99% sure the page does require JS to load properly.

Is there a way to load the page from 'within' the JS like you suggest but like a 'proper' reload?

Comment: It depends on the page. For simple, non-professional pages, it's sometimes possible, but for large, complicated, professional pages like Amazon, I seriously doubt it. You might be able to take a week or two to try to study Amazon's JS and identify which functions need to run, and *if* they're not in a private closure, patch and run them, but that's not worth it and is still unlikely to work.

Comment: You might be able to figure out how to condense Puppeteer into a bookmarklet and use *it* to scrape without reloading the page, but it's meant to be used server-side and may not work client-side. A userscript is by far the best option for developers, but if you want to distribute to others, you could write a Chrome extension too. Either way, the people who consume your script will *have* to install an extension - either yours, or a userscript manager.

Comment: Another option is for you to set up a server and make the requests to Amazon from there, instead of from the client's machine. That way, the client won't have to reload the page (until your server tells them that it's time to do so)